# Conditionally including a library for different iOS SDK versions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I'm sure this has got a simple answer, but it's stumping me :(

I'm trying to build an app that will run on iOS versions 4.3 and 5.0.  I'm fine with the idea of checking for capabilities at runtime with `-respondsToSelector`, but in order to use the Twitter functionality I need to include the Twitter library.

That causes the compiler to fail when building for 4.3, which I'd expect.  According to the Apple docs (at the very bottom of [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html)), it's possible to link frameworks conditionally - but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set the Other Linker flags to do this.  Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Target -> Build Settings, search for Other Linker Flags and click on the type of release (Debug or Release) and then on the bottom right, click Add Build Setting -> Add Conditional Setting and that will give you the SDK popup and the ability to specify any additional flags.

Comment: Thanks - I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 16):

You should also link the framework with the flag "Optional".
You can set this at the "Build Phases" panel at the point "Link Binary With Libraries".

[image: see the image , you can switch "Required" to "Optional"]

you can switch "Required" to "Optional"