# Conditionally specify an external static library in an XCode4 iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I have some externally pre-compiled libraries for iOS some for debug and some for release
I can just "add new files" to the project with the .a files  but this is for all configurations. I want some when Debug is built, and the others when Release is built.

I did it by putting the libraries in the OTHER_LDFGLAGS setting.
They have two fields one for Debug and one for Release  I just put the paths to the files in there. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue earlier today - the suggested solution was to add the libraries to the `Other Linker Flags` setting on a per-configuration basis.  The details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723783/conditionally-including-a-library-for-different-ios-sdk-versions).

Comment: thanks - I eventually got there, though editing a list of libraries in that long string is ... ( must resort to editing the XML properties  for a big list :)