# Library not loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I added Social.framework in my application in the same way i use to add the other frame works. I have downloaded xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 . but my application crashes with follwing error only on device. It works fine on simulator.

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/FC88291D-2052-45D6-A7BB-65CE340F07BF/Uploading       Image.app/Uploading Image
 Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I was getting this exact error. My app currently has a deployment target of 5.1. I wanted to add Facebook sharing. I found this old post, [Conditionally including a library for different iOS SDK versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723783/conditionally-including-a-library-for-different-ios-sdk-versions). All I did was set "Social.framework" to 'optional' and it did the trick, then my app would run on ios 5.1 and ios 6.0. Of course you need to do checks at runtime for what OS the device is running otherwise you could run into a crash if you try to access social.framework in ios 5.1 or earlier. Hope that helps!

Comment: answer makes good sense and solves the problem thanks ;) this same problem can happen with account.framework

Comment: Take +1 for the perfect solution

Answer (score 26):

In `Xcode` go to `targets`, Go to `build phase` and search for `Social frame work` you will find that under `"Link Binary with Libraries"` section. There select `social frame work` and see there is an option on right hand side `required/optional` in that just change `required` to `optional`. Now you are able to run on all ios devices without any crashes.
[image]