# iPad 1 dyld Fatal Error

Tags: ios, ipad, dyld

I am building an Xcode project with Unity3D to multiple devices. The app runs fine on an iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPod Touch 5, and iPad 4.

Earlier builds ran fine on an iPad 1. However, the current build will not run on the iPad 1, showing the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/F64896A2-EDCB-458A-9927-B86DF3F06E5A/myapp.app/myapp
  Reason: image not found
```

I have made sure that the Social.framework Framework is being linked (and set to required). I am building for arm6 + arm7, targeting iOS 5.1. The iPad 1 runs iOS 5.1.1. I am using Xcode 5.0 and Unity 3.5.7.

What could be causing this issue and how can it be fixed?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library not loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406686/library-not-loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Social Framework is only available in iOS 6 and later. iPad 1 only supports iOS 5.1.1. For reasons I've never fully understood, the compiler doesn't catch this and let's you try to do things that you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: The compiler doesn't catch this because it's not a compiler error, it's a runtime error. At compile time, the compiler sees that the use of the given framework and its classes are perfectly valid for the Base SDK you have chosen for your project. Having said that, it would be REAL nice of Xcode had a tool that said "given my Deployment Target setting, point out frameworks that should be optional and point out code that uses APIs that don't exist through all supported versions."

Comment: Seriously? I take the time to help you understand what is going on (and others up vote my comment) and you actually post such a link. Wow. Are you just having a bad day or something?

Comment: I should not have posted that link. I have removed it and offer my apologies.